# Toggle replace text upon action(s)

Tags: jquery

I have an element that when clicked it slides down to show the rest of the content, it says "*Show More Information*".

What I need is to change that text when clicked to expand to say "*Show Less Information*", but then change it back to "*Show More Information*" when collapsed.

Here's a fiddle that can be used as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/QWB4J/1/

I tried using `.replaceWith` but it only works when expanding and not collapsing.

Any help it's greatly appreciated.

**EDIT-**

Here's a fiddle with the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/QWB4J/24/

Solution provided by **willw**.

Comment: Just use `.text()` to set the content. Which message you have to set depends on the current content of the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add something like this after the toggleClass call:

```
  $(".desc").html($(".desc").hasClass("collapse") ? "Less" : "More");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks willw, your solution works great. Diode's solution works great too, but I chose yours since it uses less code. Just a quick question: Is your solution using if/else just in an optimized way? Sorry, I'm relatively new to jQuery. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this

```
$(this).prev("div.more-content").slideToggle(500, function() {
    var s = $(".desc").toggleClass("collapse").hasClass("collapse");
        if(s){
            $(".more-title span").html("Show Less Information");
        }else{
            $(".more-title span").html("Show More Information");
        }
});
```

see a demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/QWB4J/10/